# Delay element / component removal in Angular 2+ without using animations

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-animations

I would like to be able to delay the removal of an element or component from the DOM without having to add a `:leave` animation to it. Is that possible?

Ideally, I should be able to apply this from outside the component, without having to mess with the component's code.

In my particular case I'm talking about components added / removed by the router-outlet. But the solution might apply to other cases, and so I'm making the question agnostic to that.

Comment: Can you provide us informations why you try to do the removal without :leave (alternatively you can make an animation with state and afterwards navigate/destroy your component).

Comment: @JonathanStellwag I need to do a few things that cannot be done with plain Angular animations, so I'm going with a custom CSS + TypeScript animation approach instead. I did end up using a :leave animation that does nothing in order to keep the element around for a bit. But I'd rather use something less hacky. Some official way of keeping elements around (if there is one) without having to add a non-animation to them.

Comment: @cesarbrie How did you resolve the animation duration? The hack seems alright to use, but can you use dynamic duration in Angular animations?